# connection refused on localhost 25 (apache James)

Tags: 12.04, apache2, mail, mail-server, telnet

I was looking at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485583/fail-to-connect-to-james-server-localhost), but all that I gather is that it could be a problem with the OS and not James precisely:

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ bin/james start
Starting Apache James Server App...
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ cat log/james-server.log 
INFO  02:23:21,406 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@3ee0b7: startup date [Wed Aug 15 02:23:21 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  03:33:22,785 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@13336f: startup date [Wed Aug 15 03:33:22 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  11:26:26,082 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@3ee0b7: startup date [Wed Aug 15 11:26:26 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  11:40:31,812 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@d51c6c: startup date [Wed Aug 15 11:40:31 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  13:00:10,698 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@3ee0b7: startup date [Wed Aug 15 13:00:10 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  13:59:51,478 | org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext | Refreshing org.apache.james.container.spring.context.JamesServerApplicationContext@13d1929: startup date [Wed Aug 15 13:59:51 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

The [quick start](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html) specifies:

```
Step 7: Test
############

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 172.16.1.131 SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server 3.0-beta4) ready Sat, 6 Nov 2010 17:31:33 +0100 (CET)
ehlo test
```

However, it's not showing in netstat:

```
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ bin/james start
Starting Apache James Server App...
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ 
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$ netstat -l --numeric-ports | grep james
thufir@dur:~/apache-james-3.0-beta4$
```

So, bingo, that's the key, I think.  why doesn't James show in netstat if it's indeed running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is not a misconfiguration or something? For instance, are you sure it runs on port 25? I have had a similar issue with a server I had written, which I tried to telnet on port 7980, when I had asked it to bind to port 7908.

If I were in your shoes the first diagnostics I would run myself is a netstat to make sure that the server is indeed listening on that port. `Netstat` appears to be just the tool for the job. You might try in a command line something like this: `netstat -l --numeric-ports | grep james`, and see what you can make out of that. If you are not a command line fan, you can use the application `Network tools`, go to `Netstat`, and from the bullet list activate the choice `Display: Active Network Services.`

If it is indeed running on that port, my next thought would be a firewall or something. Have you tried to reach on the server from another host, on the same network?

**[EDIT]:** A quick look at the [quick start](http://james.apache.org/server/3/quick-start.html) guide suggests that in order to be able to run James properly, you need libc6 installed on Linux !! - `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libc6-dev-i386`. If you have ensured libgc6 is installed, and you have properly added domains and users, though it still doesn't seem to work, you might want to go through the configuration files. Of particular interest seem to be the following: `smtpsever.conf`, `pop3server.conf`, and perhaps `database.properties` and `jmx.properties`. PLEASE NOTE that you should be careful while editing these files. I suggest that you look for hints as to why your server is not binding to the address properly. I DO NOT know the files' contents ahead of time, so I can not advise on edits.

NOTE: If all else fails, you might want to try using james via the java cli:

```
usage: java org.apache.james.cli.ServerCmd --host <arg> <command>
    -h,--host </arg>   node hostname or ip address
    -p,--port </arg>   remote jmx agent port number
```

Comment: bingo.  not showing in netstat.  so, is it even running?  I think it **is** misconfigured.  although, I didn't configure anything at all.

Comment: To be 100% sure it is not working, also try this, while james is supposed to be running: netstat -l --numeric ports | grep 25

Comment: just one result from that: `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10025    /tmp/.esd-1001/socket`  so...James isn't running on any ports near as I can tell..?  closed question I think.  yes?

Comment: See my edit on my question.

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981867/connection-refused-how-to-configure-apache-james](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981867/connection-refused-how-to-configure-apache-james)